# WSO2 ESB - can it support concept with bridging webservice and MQ messages?

Tags: wso2-esb

is it possible to implement following concept with WSO2 ESB:

- http listener for webservices with a method to be called (SOAP)
- java routine to process message
- same routine to put message to MQ queue Q1
- same routine to get answer message from MQ queue Q2
- return with processed answered message to webservice caller

or it's better to go with J2EE server and handle messaging part fully through java code?

Regards, Nikola

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well now usecase is much more clear so that we can go ahead and implement it. There are two ways of doing this.

## First Approach

1. Write a Proxy(HTTP to JMS) service which accepts HTTP requests and
   place it in JMS Q1 using the jms sender.
2. Then write another proxy (JMS to JMS), which picks the messages from
   JMS Q1, process it and place it in JMS Q2.
3. Finally create another proxy (JMS to HTTP) to get the message from
   JMS Q2 and send it back to the client using the respond mediator.

## Second Approach

1. Create a proxy service (HTTP to JMS) and use store mediator to store the message into JMS Q1.
2. Create a Forwarding Message Processor to listen to Q1 and pick the message, process it, place it in Q2.
3. Then create another forwarding message processor to listen to Q2, and send it back to the client using a reply sequence in the message processor.

Choose which ever the way you like and let me know how it goes.

Comment: We hit another obstacle, it look like that IBM MQ Series must be installed on same server as WSO2 ESB and not just to be connected with WSO2 ESB over network where WSO2 is just MQ series client.

Comment: This can not be the case. If both are implementing JMS API they should be complaint with each other. Literally WSO2 ESB should connect to an IBM MQ running on a remote machine given the correct connection url.

Answer (score 0):

You can use ESB to implement this. But your usecase is not that clear to me. Appreciate if you can explain your usecase in functional perspective. Anyway you have HTTP(S)/JMS listeners and senders with ESB . You can't listen to a SOAP web service using ESB. What you can do is listen to HTTP traffic. Create a proxy that listens to HTTP traffic and send the message to JMS queue Q1 ussing JMS end point. Then write a JMS listener proxy to listen to the answers in Q2. Once it is received you can call the endpoint web service using send or call mediator. This is how I understood your usecase. I have no idea  on transformation of data in Q1 and place it in to Q2 due to wired requirements specified above. It looks simple HTTP to JMS switching usecase to me.

Comment: Functionaly use case is: 1. client application invokes webservice method on ESB 2. ESB trasforms XML and puts message on Q1 (note that method still doesn't return any value to client, TCP session is not yet closed) . 3. system on other end of Q1 process the message and return result XML to Q2. 4. ESB should transform incoming XML from Q2 and return it as result in invoked method (webservice/HTTP listener can now close TCP session). Hope this description makes it more clear. Essentially synchronous webservice call should be transformed into asynchronous put/get message actions.